# After a hard reset in Git is there a way truncate the branch so it doesn't reflect a fast-forward?

Tags: git, version-control

On my main branch I had some code committed.  I needed to rollback my code 2 commits.  In order to do that I did a

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

I thought that this would truncate any commits done after the current HEAD setting however the status reflects that I have 2 commits that I should fast-forward.

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/release-DECEMBER-2019' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
(use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

How can I truncate this so I am no longer 'behind by 2 commits'.  All in all I'm looking to rewind 2 commits and start fresh from there.  I hope that's clear.  Problem is that after I "rewind" or do my reset --hard GIT reflects that I should do a pull to catch up.

Comment: That means there are 6 commits on the remote you don't have locally - if you want them you need to pull, if you don't you need to force push. Worth noting that the use of `truncate` here is a bit weird - normally `truncate` is used to mean deleting _old and unwanted_ commits - not the latest commits that directly affect the HEAD. Please update the question to indicate your intent.

Comment: Something may be off here.  Were those two commits you deleted already pushed to the repository, and is anyone else using this branch?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I'm actually I'm looking to discard the fast-forward'ed items.  I'm looking to remove the committed changes and start from the point where I reset to.

Comment: Discard from where? Please update the question to indicate your intent.

Comment: I updated the question.  No one else is using this branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You will need to *force push*, `git push --force origin branch`.  There are a bunch of caveats about that, which boil down to: *don't force push without telling other users of that name first.*  If there are no other users, there's no one else to tell, and you can force push any time.

#### Long

Each Git repository has its own branches.  There are two repositories here: yours, with your current branch (I'll assume it's named `release-DECEMBER-2019`), and theirs, with their branches (I'll assume the same name for this one).

Your Git repository remembers *their* (`origin`'s) branches using your *remote-tracking names*, such as `origin/release-DECEMBER-2019`.

Remember that Git commit hash IDs are universal—your Git and their Git use the *same* hash IDs for the commits that you both share—but the branch *names* are independent.  So here, where we use single uppercase letters to stand in for commit hash IDs, the "letters" mean the same thing in both Git repositories.

Let's draw what's in *their* Git repository right now:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- release-DECEMBER-2019
```

That is, in *their* Git repository, the name `release-DECEMBER-2019` identifies commit `J`.

Now let's draw what's in *your* repository before the `git reset --hard`.  (I am of course guessing here.  You may want to have your Git do this for you, using `git log --decorate --oneline --graph`.  This draws vertically, with newer commits towards the top, rather than horizontally with newer commits towards the right, but produces a similar graph drawing.)

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- release-DECEMBER-2019 (HEAD), origin/release-DECEMBER-2019
```

The `(HEAD)` notation here shows where your Git's HEAD is attached, to your branch named `release-DECEMBER-2019`.  Both this branch name, and your `origin/release-DECEMBER-2019` name, point to existing commit `J`.

You now run `git reset --hard HEAD~2`.  Your Git counts two first-parent steps back from commit `J` to reach commit `H`, and moves the *name* `release-DECEMBER-2019` to point to commit `H` (while also resetting your index and work-tree to contain the files from commit `H`):

```
...--F--G--H   <-- release-DECEMBER-2019 (HEAD)
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/release-DECEMBER-2019
```

(We can bend the graph around however we like when we need to stick labels on it, as long as each commit continues to point back to its parents.  On a more flexible drawing medium we'd just use curved arrows from the branch names, perhaps.)

But *their* repository still has the chain going to `J` with *their* branch name pointing to commit `J`.  To fix this, you need to have your Git call up their Git, give them any new commits they need and don't have—which is no commits; they have all the ones they need, plus two more—and then ask or tell them to change *their* `release-DECEMBER-2019` name to point to commit `H`.

Asking them politely will get a refusal: they'll say, in effect: *No!  If I do that, I'll lose access to commits `I` and `J`.*  Of course, that's precisely what you want.  So you need to send them a forceful command:

```
git push --force origin release-DECEMBER-2019
```

This sends them any new commits (none), then sends them a forceful command: *Set your `release-DECEMBER-2019` to point to commit `H`!*  Assuming they obey,<sup>1</sup> your Git sees that their Git has changed *their* `release-DECEMBER-2019` to point to `H`, and updates your `origin/release-DECEMBER-2019` accordingly:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- release-DECEMBER-2019 (HEAD), origin/release-DECEMBER-2019
            \
             I--J   [abandoned]
```

Your Git will now say that your branch and your remote-tracking name, `origin/release-DECEMBER-2019`, agree and there is nothing to fast-forward or merge.

---

<sup>1</sup>They *might* still refuse, but by default they will obey.  If they do refuse, you must look into settings in *their* Git (or on GitHub or whatever controls "their" Git) to see why they refused.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the hazards of rebasing (rewriting history) you can do a `git push -f origin release-DECEMBER-2019`. This will force push the new version of your branch to origin.

*Do not do if anyone has used your branch. Could/will cause conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very careful here.

Rebasing rewrites the history of your branch. This will cause problems if many developers use the same branch.

What I would do right now is:

> - Pull from remote (basically, undo your hard-rebase command)

Now you are back to the point from before you executed your hard-rebase command.

To undo your last two commits:

> 1- Go to remote branch and REVERT the commits (not reset!)

Whatever server you are using (Github, Azure..etc), there should be a button beside any commit that says "Revert". Reverting a commit will create a new commit which is the opposite-work of the original commit. This is basically undoing the original commit.

> 2- Pull remote to local to see the revert-commit

Means, remote master now will have two new commits (reverts of the two original commits). Now your local is behind remote by two, when you pull you will sync, and when you look at your code you will find that the original commits' work was undone.

Now anyone who uses the branch, will have two additional commits than need to be pulled. This way, your original work will be undone on all and any developer's machine.

Comment: My last commit was done as a merge.  It seems I can't revert to a merge point.

Comment: @Dale: you *can* revert a merge, with some effort, but in your situation—a private branch on both sides—you really don't want to: this leaves a time bomb for yourself later.

Comment: Yeah.  I agree.  Better now then later.